# ListenHTTP does not set correct Content-Type

Tags: apache-nifi

I am posting json to the url provided by `ListenHTTP` processor. Although I set the content-type to `application/json` when sending the request, the flowfile content-type is always `text/plain`.

Is there a way to get the correct content type?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should use HandleHttpRequest and HandleHttpResponse instead https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.HandleHttpRequest/

Answer (score 1):

`HTTP Headers to receive as Attributes (Regex) = .*`

but it will be set as an attribute `content-type` (maybe with prefix - i don't remember)

when nifi uses `mime.type` to render content in flowfile preview

UpdateAttribute could solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Actually ran into this exact issue today on NiFi v1.11.3.  Ended up sending an additional, custom HTTP "mime.type" header with "application/json" that resolved the issue.

```
    $Data = Get-Content .\data.json 

    $MethodParams = @{

        Uri = 'http://0.0.0.0:[PORT]/[Endpoint]'
        Method = 'POST'
        Body = $Data
        ContentType = 'application/json'
        Headers     = @{ 'mime.type' = "application/json" }
    }

    Invoke-RestMethod @MethodParams
```